# Adding a text to the AutoConnect(line) in visio drawing using C# code

Tags: c#, visio

I have create two shapes in Visio and using `Shape.AutoConnect` method I am able to connect the  two shapes using the below code. I want to add name to the connector line using C# code as per the below screen shot.

Sample Visio Drawing:
[image: Sample Visio Drawing]

Following is my code to connect two shapes.

````
   Visio.Shape visioRectShape = visioPage.Drop(visioRectMaster, 4.25, 5.25);
   visioRectShape.Text = from[i];

   Visio.Master visioCircleMaster3 = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Circle");
   Visio.Shape visioCircleShape3 = visioPage.Drop(visioCircleMaster3, 4.85, 5.85);
   visioCircleShape3.Text = to[i];

   visioRectShape.AutoConnect(visioCircleShape3,Visio.VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirRight);```


**But can not get any information how to add a text for the connector line. Please help**
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code by taking the last shape count, then we can get the shape used for the connector line. Then only i will be able to add text to the connector object.

[Sample Code for connector Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRUch.png)

````
Visio.Shape vsoConnectorShape = visioPage.Shapes.get_ItemU(visioPage.Shapes.Count);
vsoConnectorShape.Text = @"ololo";```
````

Comment: I did not know this nuance of the definition of a shape: `visioPage.Shapes.get_ItemU(visioPage.Shapes.Count)`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul and Surrogate that passing in the connector object is preferable, but there is also the [`Shape.GluedShapes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.gluedshapes) method, which could be helpful here.  For example, given this diagram where I've added the shape IDs for reference:

[image: flowchart sample]

```cs
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();
    // See this link for more details on GetRunningVisio():
    // https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html

    var fromShp = vApp.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID[6];
    var toShp = vApp.ActivePage.Shapes.ItemFromID[8];
    
    var connIds = fromShp.GluedShapes(Visio.VisGluedShapesFlags.visGluedShapesOutgoing1D, "", toShp);
```

`connIds` is then an array of the respective connector IDs:

[image]

Normally this would be a single item but you could then go on to inspect the shapes if your scenario is different.

Answer (score 0):

At you side you have not defined shape - connector line !
**This shape is last shape which added to this page**.
I have not there IDE with C#, may be this code can work:

```
Visio.Shape vsoConnectorShape = visioPage.Shapes(visioPage.Shapes.Count);
vsoConnectorShape.Text = @"ololo";
```

My code in VBA works fine, I just changed the code a little bit from the [example from the MS website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.autoconnect#example), I assigned values to variables using IDs.

```
Sub AutoConnect_Example()
Dim vsoShape1 As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoShape2 As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoConnectorShape As Visio.Shape
Set vsoShape1 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(1)
Set vsoShape2 = Visio.ActivePage.Shapes(2)
vsoShape1.AutoConnect vsoShape2, visAutoConnectDirRight
' define last added shape '    
Set vsoConnectorShape = ActivePage.Shapes(ActivePage.Shapes.Count) 
' change text '
vsoConnectorShape.Text = "ololo"    
End Sub
```

This gif show how VBA code works at my side
[image: Find last shape aka connector]

Comment: I think this code is not working. I am getting error as 'shape cannot be used as method'

Comment: Just try. I'm not expert in C#, you can modify my working VBA code !

Comment: @NiharSahoo You need to define the connector before doing the autoconnect, then get the correct syntax for the autoconnect statement.

Comment: Paul, I try this way: drop connector, define it as variable and use AutoConnect. In this case I get new connector after AutoConnect (not that connector which was defined before.

Comment: You can't just make up code as you go along, read the syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.autoconnect

Comment: @Paul, I just changed the code a little bit, I assigned values to variables using IDs. I already had a connector on the page with ID = 3, this shape corresponded to the variable `vsoConnectorShape`. this variable was used in the line that uses the autoconnect method `vsoShape1.AutoConnect vsoShape2, visAutoConnectDirRight, vsoConnectorShape`. But if you look at this [gif-animation](https://i.imgur.com/rxHFQNU.gif) you will see that a new connector was added !  **PS** My side is using visio 2019, I was surprised to see a new shape being added

Comment: @Surrogate - sorry, I was commenting on Nihar's code.

Comment: `expression.AutoConnect(ToShape, PlacementDir, Connector)`, where _Connector_ is optional. I think in this case Nihar's code is correct