# How do I connect Visio shapes only to the marked positions using Glue?

Tags: c#, visio

Below is the code that I used to find the shape with a connector. But I will need the connector to start and end on the marked spot (Mid-Point of side of Rectangle) as displayed on the image.[image]

```
// Drop Shape
Visio.Master visioMaster = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Rectangle");
Visio.Shape visioShape = visioPage.Drop(visioMaster, 0.0, 0.0);

Visio.Master visioMaster1 = visioStencil.Masters.get_ItemU(@"Rectangle");
Visio.Shape visioShape1 = visioPage.Drop(visioMaster1, 0.0, 1.0);

// Add a dynamic connector to the page using glue.
Visio.Shape vsoConnectorShape = visioShape.ContainingPage.Drop(app.ConnectorToolDataObject, 0.0, 0.0);

// Set the connector properties, using different arrows, colors, and patterns for many-to-many relationships.

// Connect the starting point.
Visio.Cell cellBeginX = vsoConnectorShape.get_CellsSRC(1, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DBeginY);
cellBeginX.GlueTo(visioShape.get_CellsSRC(1, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX));

// Connect the ending point.
Visio.Cell cellEndX = vsoConnectorShape.get_CellsSRC(1, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.vis1DEndY);
cellEndX.GlueTo(visioShape1.get_CellsSRC(1, (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visXFormPinY));
```

I want my line to start from mid point of side of one rectangle and end at mid point of side of another rectangle as i have marked by black bold line on the below snap shot. I  have manually modified the lines in my new second snap shot. I hope my question will be more clear now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean as 'marked spot' ? Exist [connection points](https://visiozone.com/?p=389) or something else?

Comment: red marked spot on the rectangles.

Comment: These _marked spots_ (connection points) are purple! You must know their    order for connect shapes in positions that you need. Or use [AutoConnnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231296/adding-a-text-to-the-autoconnectline-in-visio-drawing-using-c-sharp-code) opportunity...